# How can I get commits from certain file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to get all commits from **certain** file. In API docs, I only found how to get all commits from repository. But is it possible to get it from single file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the blame range.
with this request `GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path/blame`
The updated documentation can be found here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-blame-from-repository

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `GET /projects/:id/repository/commits` and then use the `?path=` flag, as documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits)

For example, these are the commits to the `README` file of GitLab itself: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/278964/repository/commits?path=README.md